# Add buttons dynamically in aspx-file

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, dynamically-generated

I would like to add a button for every entry in a list that is prepared in the code behind, it could call a method and send the list object as an argument. What is the best way of doing this?

Inline code? If so how can I access the list? Should it be a global variable? etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you want just add your controls to aspx file, you can use `PlaceHolder control`, this control `is made for this specific need`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

Sample of code

```
         HtmlButton myButton = new HtmlButton();

         myButton.InnerText = "Button 1";
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);

         myButton = new HtmlButton();
         myButton.InnerText = "Button 2";
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);

         myButton = new HtmlButton();
         myButton.InnerText = "Button 3";
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);

         myButton = new HtmlButton();
         myButton.InnerText = "Button 4";
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);
```

Note : If you want customize your render by listing, you can use Repeater, DataList, GridView or another controls.

Comment: Nice, and how can I use css to style the buttons as the ones in the aspx-file? I.e where to I assign a css class for them for instance?

Comment: And also, I did what you wrote in the Page_Load and added an eventhandler to the button. But when the button is clicked only the Page_Load method is called, the placeholder has no components in it?